# Toggle Firefox Kiosk Mode

Tags: firefox, browser, firefox-addon-webextensions

I want to toggle Firefox's **Kiosk Mode**(F11) via JS/Browser API for my code.

I dont mean the HTML 5 Fullscreen Mode, I want to hover my taskbar to see my tabs.

How could I manage this?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get this HTML5 fullscreen function working in Firefox too?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20326489/how-can-i-get-this-html5-fullscreen-function-working-in-firefox-too)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, this is currently not possible. The only supported method for getting a tab in fullscreen mode using code is making use of the HTML5 fullscreen API.

You might want to file a bug for it, but explain yourself clearly (the difference between the fullscreen mode F11 and fullscreen mode HTML5 in Firefox).

The link to file a bug is here, choose the product Toolkit:
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/